# Strong maximum principle for weak solutions still holds?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, maximum-principle

By De Giorge, Nash and Moser solutions of
\begin{equation} 
    \operatorname{div} (A(x) Du) = 0
\end{equation}
where $Du$ denotes the gradient of $u$ and $A$ is a $\lambda,\Lambda$ elliptic matrix. That is,
\begin{equation}
    \lambda|\xi|^2\le\langle A_\pm(x)\,\xi,\xi\rangle \le \Lambda|\xi|^2,
\end{equation}
for constants $0< \lambda \le \Lambda$ can be only Hölder continuous. So the classical strong maximum principle, see for instance Fanghua Lin,
[image]
can not be applyed because the solutin can not be sufficiently smooth. If the equation
[image]

was satisfyied only in the weak sense, the SMP istill holds?

I know that already exists similar questions here but the different context difficult the undertand.

Comment: In this context the SMP follows from Harnack inequality. If $m$ is the infimum of $u$, then $v=u-m$ has infimum 0. If $v(x_0)=0$, then $\sup_B v \leq C \inf_B v=0$ for any ball $B$ containing $x_0$. The set of zeros of $v$ is then open and closed and $v=0$.